# Weird behavior on clear dates

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm working with `react 17.0.2` and `next 12.0.0`, and use `react-date-range` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-date-range)

I have setted a default dates, and when the component is mounted, everything is fine. You can see my example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-17-forked-6p10ss?file=/src/App.js

Steps to reproduce the errror:

1. When CodeSandbox loads, you can see that the calendar works fine.
2. I choose only "startDate", I don't choose "endDate"
3. Now I click on the "Clear" button. (I hope that the calendar returns to the initial state)
4. If I choose any day, it will be selected as "endDate", "startDate" is now selected in the first enabled day.

Does anyone know when this is happening to me?

I hope that when i cleared the dates, doesn't have any date selected. This error doesn't happen if i choose both dates, start and end.

Comment: I think you didn't update your codesandbox! The initial date are setting `endDate`.

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto doesn't matter which dates i have setted on start, the problem is the same. If i do click on clear button (back to put initialDates on my state) without selected the "endDate" from the calendar, when i go to select any date again, the fist date is already selected. Why this happen, if the date setted now, is exacty the same on mounted?

Comment: I think i'm not getting what you want.. After i click in `clear`, the calendar selects the current day and if i click in any date now, its setting the start date. Could you explain with more details the behavior you expect?

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto please open the codesandbox, select an startDate, then select an endDate. The range must be higlighted and correctly selected. If you click on clear dates, everything is fine. Now, just selected an startDate (dont selected and endDate) and click on "Clear" button. Now hover any date and see what happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a state to control the `focusedRange` option.

```js
const [focusedRange, setFocusedRange] = useState([0, 0]);

const handleClear = () => {
    setState(initialDates);
    setFocusedRange([0, 0]);
  };

<DateRangePicker
   focusedRange={focusedRange}
   onRangeFocusChange={setFocusedRange}
   ...
```

When you select the `startDate`, the `DateRangePicker` internally sets the focusRange to `[0,1]`. So you also need to reset that value when click on clear button. In this case for the default value `[0,0]`.

You can check a little more about this information [here](https://github.com/hypeserver/react-date-range/issues/400#issuecomment-726596653).

Comment: OMG luis, i need you here, with me <3 lol, thanks a lot, is the second help that you give me today.

Comment: Excuseme, i need make a little change. I want to have all the state from calendar in a only state objet, for avoid many renderings. So, i put "state" and "focusedRange" as properties from a new object. Now, i need to pass a new function instead ``onRangeFocusChange={setFocusedRange}``, im trying ``onRangeFocusChange={item => handleFocusChange(item)}`` and in ``handleFocusChange`` i made `` setCalendarConfig({
      ...calendarConfig,
      focusedRange: item,
    });`` but doesnt work. Have an idea about what i must to do in order that this works?

Comment: I've created a fork code from the previous code sample. Take a look [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-daterangerpick-with-transition-one-state-i81soc?file=/src/App.js). Cheers.

Comment: 100pts for Griffindor. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: could you helpme one more time? This approach doesnt work when i add "scroll={{enabled: true}}" property to my calendar :(

Comment: I'll try to take a look when I have time.

Comment: For the transition work with scroll you need to change all classes of your `css` file removing `.rdrMonths` and adding `.rdrInfiniteMonths .rdrMonth`. But this will mess up when you are changing the month by scrolling - and to solve this new issue you will need to go further and try to handle the code when the user is scrolling (maybe removing the class or something like that). I beleieve the easiest way is to choose with or without the scroll.

Comment: may thanks @LuisPauloPinto You saved my day by sharing the code solution