# React-date-range clear dates with focusedRange

Tags: reactjs, next.js, datepicker

im using React 17.0.2 and next 12.0.0, and the library https://github.com/hypeserver/react-date-range/

I have a problem with onRangeFocusChange, if i add the property `scroll={{enabled: true}}` to my calendar

There's a time ago i made this question [Weird behavior on clear dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72436606/weird-behavior-on-clear-dates)

The solution provides by the user Luis works great, but when i add `scroll={{enabled: true}}` to my calendar component, the problem showns again.

My calendar

```
            <DateRangePicker
              preventSnapRefocus
              showPreview
              showSelectionPreview
              direction={isMobile ? "vertical" : "horizontal"}
              focusedRange={calendarConfig.focusedRange}
              minDate={new Date()}
              monthDisplayFormat="MMMM yyyy"
              months={2}
              ranges={calendarConfig.calendarDates}
              scroll={scrollSettings()}
              showDateDisplay={false}
              showMonthAndYearPickers={false}
              weekdayDisplayFormat="EEEEEE"
              onChange={item => handleDatesChange([item.selection])}
              onRangeFocusChange={item => handleFocusChange(item)}
            />
```

**What i want?**

> I want that when the user clicked on "Clear" button, doesn't had no one date selected.

**What's happen?**

> When i click on "Clear" button, now is automatically selected the date of today.

If i remove `scroll` property, i can see everything fine, but i need add this property.